# React Naitve Element Input left Icon displaced?

Tags: javascript, react-native, input

I am using react native input elements and font awesome in an expo project. Here is my code snippet,

```
import { Input, Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';


<Input autoFocus
              ref={(input) => { this.email = input; }}
              placeholder='Name'
              leftIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'hospital-o'}}
              onChangeText={(text)=>this.handleChangeText({name:text})}
              value={this.state.name}
              name="name"
            />
```

However, left icon is displaced by a small marging inside the input element in Android. Screen shot attached (Pink line denoting displacement),

[image]
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you share expo code so that i can check?

Comment: Are you asking for the full code of the component?

Comment: yeah like workable live component in the expo snack

Comment: Sorry, I have not tested in expo snack. Using a android device for test.

Comment: I'm saying add your code to expo snack., and then provide me the link so there I can check

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@himu/816187

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `leftIconContainerStyle` so after that it becomes <

```
<Input autoFocus
              ref={(input) => { this.email = input; }}
              placeholder='Name'
              leftIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'hospital-o'}}
              onChangeText={(text)=>this.handleChangeText({name:text})}
              value={this.state.name}
              leftIconContainerStyle = {{marginLeft:-20}}
              name="name"
            />
```

try once , and tell me if any doubts are there

Comment: Thanks. leftIconContainerStyle has some effect. Icon is now adjusting to left. Just adjust the value of this property.